# How to delete vowels in a string

Tags: c, string

I want to write a program that deletes the vowels in a string. This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f (char s[100])
{
    int ok=0;
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if ((s[i]=='a')||(s[i]=='e')||(s[i]=='i')||(s[i]=='o')||(s[i]=='u'))
        {
            ok++;
            strcpy (s+i,s+i+1);
        }
    }
    printf ("%s",s);
}

int main ()
{
    f("alina");
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it my program stops working. The same happens when I debug it: when I get to the line `strcpy (s+i,s+i+1);` I get an error message: "program has stopped working". Am I doing something wrong? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is , you're calling

```
f("alina");
```

with a *string literal* (`"alina"`), which is usually present in *read-only* memory and not modifiable. Any attempt to modify the *string literal* will result to undefined behavior.

Instead, you can do something like

```
int main (void)
{
    char arr[] = "alina";

    f(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

which

- defines an array [modifiable] called `arr`
- initialize the array with a value `"alina"`
- pass the array to function `f()`.

Also, make a note about the proper signature of `main()`.

Comment: If you'd said "string literal" instead of "string", this would be right... both the original code and yours pass a "string", though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems in your program.

First of all string literals are immutable. You may not change string literals. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

And secondly you may not use `strcpy` when the ranges overlap each other. Instead of `strcpy` you should use `memmove`

From the C Standard

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, **the behavior is
>   undefined**.

And to copy always a whole part of the string to remove only one symbol is inefficient.

Also statement

```
printf ("%s",s);
```

should be moved from the function in main.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you can use the twix trick, aka two finger method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strip_vowels(char *s) {
    for (char *p1 = s, *p2 = s; (*p1 = *p2) != '\0'; p2++)
        p1 += !strchr("aeiou", *p1);
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    char msg[] = "Hello world\n";
    fputs(strip_vowels(msg), stdout);
    return 0;
}
```